# Html is showing extra text

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code looks wrong:

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first'),
         more = document.getElementById('more'),
         trigger = document.createElement('span');
    trigger.id = 'trigger';
    trigger.innerHTML = 'Show less';
    first.appendChild(trigger);
    function toggleDiv() {
      var state = more.className,
           text = trigger.innerHTML;
      more.className = (state == 'open') ? 'closed' : 'open';
      trigger.innerHTML = (text == 'Show more') ? 'Show less' : 'Show more';
    }
    toggleDiv();
    if (trigger.addEventListener) {
        trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleDiv, false);
    } else if (trigger.attachEvent) {
      trigger.attachEvent('onclick', toggleDiv);
    } else {
      trigger.onclick = toggleDiv;
    }
```

```css
#trigger {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #more {
        transition: ease-out .7s;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #more p:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    #more.closed {
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-600px);
        transform: translateY(-600px);
    }
    #more.open {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        max-height: 600px;
    }
    #more + p {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <p id="first">This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.<br></p>
     
    <p id="more" class="open">This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE.
    <br>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
```

I want the code to show the text when a user clicks on <kbd>Show more</kbd>

But on the webpage it also shows:

```
This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=FIRST. It could display as much or as little text as you care to show.

This is the paragraph marked with the ID=MORE. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

How can I leave out only one button for "Show more" and get rid off the text that is below it ?

Comment: The purpose of your button is to show more text and it does. What you want it to do ?

Comment: @Hearner, it does.. but there is also the same text on a webpage without clicking on a button

Comment: hum... there is not. Look at the snippet. There is your text above (which is normal) and no text below it until you click the link. `I want the code to show the text when a user clicks on button`... it does

Comment: It's work for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/kf01zbot/